# Topological equivalence for the vector space of absolutely convergent series

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I want to show that the $\ell_p$ norm and $\ell_q$ norm are not topologically equivalent if $p \neq q$ on the vector space of absolutely convergent series. I think it suffices to show that it is not possible to choose $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\|x\|_q \le \|x\|_p$ for some absolutely convergent series $x$. This is equivalent to showing that there does not exist $\alpha$ such that
$$
\frac{(\sum|x_i|^q)^\frac1q}{(\sum|x_i|^p)^\frac1p} \le \frac1\alpha
$$
if $p \neq q$ for some $x$. But I am having trouble finding this particular $x$ so that the LHS can be simplified. Can someone give a hint? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality you are trying to falsify fails only when $p \geq q$. When $p<q$ the inequality holds with $\alpha =1$. In this case you have to reverse the roles of $p$ and $q$.

So let $p >q$. In this case take $x_i=\frac 1 {i^{1/q}}$ for $i=1,2...,N$ and $0$ for $i >N$. Check that the inequality fails for sufficiently large $N$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Could you elaborate a bit on why $\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^N 1/i)^{\frac1q}}{(\sum_{i=1}^N 1/i^{p/q})^{\frac1p}} \le \frac1\alpha$ fails for sufficiently large $N$? Is it because the numerator diverges as $N\to \infty$ while the denominator converges?

Comment: Yes, exactly! @InsultedByMathematics

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!